# compare two xml files and add new tags to first xml file

Tags: java, xml

I have to xml files say abc.xml & 123.xml which are almost similar, i mean has the same content, but the second one i.e, 123.xml has more content than the earlier one. I want to read both the files using Java and to add the extra contents to abc.xml without changing its existing contents

Answer (score 1):

Java internally has xml parser. Search over net on how to use it.
Two links are given below,

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_parse_document.htm

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_dom_modify_document.htm

Simply you have to read both of them and then write logic to compare and then wrtie to combined to another file.

Answer (score 0):

XMLUnit is the key my friend. It compares two XMLs in an advanced yet simple way and easy to understand. To add a new tag, you can either do it in the good ol' string concatenation or using jDom or any similar library. Here is some good references:

http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/

http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/userguide/html/

```
String refXmlPaht = "../test1.xml";
String testXmlPaht = "../test2.xml";
Document doc1 = TransformXML.convertXmlToDom(refXmlPaht);
Document doc2 = TransformXML.convertXmlToDom(testXmlPaht);

Diff myDiff = new Diff(doc1, doc2);
XMLUnit.setIgnoreWhitespace(true);
XMLUnit.setIgnoreComments(true);
XMLUnit.setIgnoreAttributeOrder(true);

assertXMLEqual("pieces of XML are not similar ", myDiff, true);
assertTrue("but are they identical? " + myDiff, myDiff.identical());
```

this part was taken from other links in different cases.
Hit me up if you have more questions!

Comment: Inorder to use xmlunit, i've to add additional .jar files in my project. Is there any other way to solve this problem using normal java classes which is available in jdk

Comment: @NIDHEESHKRISHNA Adding external jars is an essential thing in Java. But yes you can. You can read both files as a string and compare them line by line. You can use 2 BufferedReader to read both files. Check which file is the bigger because it will most likely be the one with the extra information. Read line by line and add them to and add to a new empty string. Compare them using an if. Ff they are not equal then add the other missing info to that string. If you do not understand, then I will add another comment with more detail.

Comment: please explain more... i couldn't understand the details

Comment: Basically using a BufferedReader you will read the first file and another will read the other. Using reader.readLine() you will read each file line by line, compare them, and act accordingly.